# Matplotlib add a default watermark

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` for work and company policy is to include a watermark on every plot we make. Is there a way to set `matplotlib` to do this by default?

I'm currently passing each `Axes` object into a helper function which adds the watermark in the bottom left corner.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_watermark(ax):
    ax.text(ax.get_xlim()[0] + 0.1, 
            ax.get_ylim()[0] + 0.1, 
            "<Company Name>", 
            alpha=0.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x = np.fromiter((np.random.uniform() for _ in range(100)), dtype=np.float32)
y = np.fromiter((np.random.uniform() for _ in range(100)), dtype=np.float32)
ax.scatter(x, y)
add_watermark(ax)
```

I would like to modify the default behavior of `matplotlib` so that I don't have to pass each axes instance into a helper function.

Comment: if you are feeling adventurous, I suppose you can monkey-patch the constructor of the axes to include the watermark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may easily subclass and monkey-patch the default axes. So create a file *matplotlib_company.py* like this

```
import matplotlib.axes
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

class MyAxes(matplotlib.axes.Axes):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ab = AnchoredText("<company name>", loc="lower left", frameon=False,
                          borderpad=0, prop=dict(alpha=0.5))
        ab.set_zorder(0)
        self.add_artist(ab)

matplotlib.axes.Axes = MyAxes
```

Then import it everywhere you need it. I.e. the following

```
import matplotlib_company
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

creates

[image]

Comment: As of matplotlib version 3.6.2, your code does not work. Any plot including an legend will fail and plots without a legend have no `<company name>` printed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution for this is to create a "company plot template" within a separate python script (e.g. called `companyplots.py`) that's somewhere within python's [module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

You can do this either by simply having it in the same folder as your actual plots, or e.g. by creating a `/some/path/to/user_modules` folder and correctly setting the `$PYTHONPATH` variable to include the path to it.

Within this file, collect all necessary imports and setup a function with default plot settings, e.g.:

```py
def companyFigure((rows,cols),(width,height)=(768,576),dpi=72,fig_kwargs={}):
    """
    first, reset mpl style to default, then enforce a new one. 
    This is helpful when the new style does not overwrite *all* attributes 
    """
    style="ggplot" ##<- put your own style file here, if you have one
    mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
    mpl.style.use(style)

    ## that's your function:
    def add_watermark(ax):
        ax.text(ax.get_xlim()[0] + 0.1, 
                ax.get_ylim()[0] + 0.1, 
                "<Company Name>", 
                alpha=0.5)

    ## create figure with some arguments
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(rows,cols,
            figsize=(width/float(dpi),height/float(dpi)),
            dpi=dpi,
            **fig_kwargs
            )

    ## I'm presuming that you may want to have subplots somewhere down the line;
    ## for the sake of consistency, I'm thus making sure that "ax" is always a dict:
    if rows==1 and cols==1:
        ax={0:ax}

    for a in ax:
        add_watermark(a)

    return fig,ax
```

Now, all future plots can fall back to this template, simply by running:

```py
from companyplots import *

fig,ax=companyFigure((2,1),(500,300))
## do your plotting here...
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Matplotlib version 3.6 and Seaborn 0.12, I use:

```
def addwatermark(ax):
    """ Place watermark in bottom right of figure. """
    text = "<watermark>"
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(0.3, 0.1), xycoords='axes fraction', alpha=0.4, fontsize='large', rotation=45, fontweight=550)
```

You can add this in a separate `addwatermark.py` file and call `from addwatermark.py import addwatermark`.

Usage example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from addwatermark.py import addwatermark

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
addwatermark(ax)
plt.show()
```

Also Seaborn works:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from addwatermark.py import addwatermark
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
addwatermark(ax)
plt.show()
```

If you use `facetgrid` or `pairgrid` in Seaborn, the axes can be accessed through their attribute `ax`.

Matplotlib also has an [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/watermark_text.html), but that did not work with Seaborn.